# MariaDB taking ages to restore backup

Tags: mysql, backup, database, mariadb

So I did a `mysqldump` of a pretty huge db and I'm trying to restore it now using:

`mysql db_test < db_test.sql`

but it looks like it's not gonna end by the end of this year. It's been about an hour now and still "restoring". Making the backup took about 10 minutes so I'm afraid something bad is going on.

**So far:**

- I've checked that `mysqld` is consuming my cpu (up to 80% sometimes).
- There's nothing relevant to it in the logs.
- I can see the database created and filled with a ton of tables (not
  everything tho). Also, when I execute `use db_test;`, I get the
  following message:

  > Reading table information for completion of table and column names You
  >   can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
- Original db files where around 25GB, after the whole hour, `df -h` returns the same free space as before. So I guess it's not doing anything on disk.

*Something weird here is that, when checking `top`, I found out that `kworker` was consuming up to 100% of cpu sometimes, which shouldn't be happenning*

---

Any idea or anything I could do to see what's going on?

Comment: Sounds like it's busy writing to disk.

Comment: For an hour already? The db is huge, not infinite lol.

Comment: Consider disabling keys and indexes until your restore job is complete. That will traditionally give a hefty performance boost.

Comment: I'll try that out @TimBrigham. Also, I updated the question with a bit more info provided by `df -h`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds as the underlying disks are busy. The problem in restoring a large database is that each (group of) INSERT requires a flush/sync operation, which is very slow on mechanical disks (a 7200 RPM disk is in the order of ~100 IOPS).

To hasten the restore, you had to temporarily instruct MySQL/MariaDB to *not* issue flushes/syncs. To do that, interrupt the restore and edit your `/etc/my.ini` with the following two lines:

- `innodb_flush_method=nosync`
- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2`

Then restart MariaDB and retry the restore. Things should go much faster now.

After the restore, ***REMOVE THE ABOVE LINES*** or your database will have a short and bad life: flushes/syncs exists for very important reasons. While it is acceptable to turn them off for a restore, a production database should **never** run without them.

Answer (score 2):

If your underlying storage is plain old disks, for a 25GB-on-disk MySQL database, that's quite normal to experience hours-long restore - especially for some badly structured dbs (lots of tuples, indexes, etc.).

For a start compress your dump, that saves tons of I/Os and puts less stress on cache memory :

```
mysqldump foo |gzip >foo.sql.gz
zcat foo.sql.gz |mysql foo
```

In your case, since you already did the mysqldump :

```
gzip db_test.sql
zcat db_test.sql.gz |mysql db_test
```

Besides your system performance (storage, RAM, etc.), MySQL settings might have a huge impact. But that's a whole expertise there, nothing than can be handled thru a ServerFault issue...

Comment: In my case, the restoring time didn't change. It still stays at ca 1h and 15 minutes for 1.5GB uncompressed data.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the logs for lines like

```
Could not increase number of max_open_files
```

Please check your settings for `LimitNOFILE` and `LimitMEMLOCK` in Your `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service`.
After changing run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo service mysql restart`.
You don't have to set it to `infinity`, but the standard values may be to low.

In addition, setting to `infinity` sets to values limited by kernel settings.

See also:

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/could-not-increase-number-of-max_open_files-to-more-than-1024-request-1835/
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/systemd/#configuring-the-open-files-limit